# Bootstrap 4 col row grid export to csv or excel

Tags: jquery, export, bootstrap-4

I am using a div grid which I just want to copy the data out. Any bootstrap 4/jquery extension that allows this? Normal copy paste puts everything in single line

```
<div class="row h5">
    <div class="col-2">name</div>
    <div class="col-3">purchased</div>
    <div class="col-2">Date</div>
    <div class="col-1">Method</div>
    <div class="col-1">CC Reference</div>
    <div class="col-3">transId</div>
</div>
```

Comes out as this:

```
name
purchased
Date
Method
CC Reference
transId
```

But should come out tab delimited, so you can paste into any sheets app (google or excel)

Do I need to convert my code back to normal table tr td format?